# Monitor and Conditionally Act Upon Continuous Output of Command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, monitoring

In bash, I have a command running in screen that is effectively:

```
while true
do
  echo $RANDOM
  sleep 1
done
```

The output of which is:

```
12396
19683
31641
...
```

I'd like to pipe that into something like grep/awk and I match a specific pattern, such as `12345`, I want a command to run.

I don't want to capture the full output of the running command - it may run for a very long time before a match is found and I don't want to waste space on the machine.

Can this be done easily in bash?

In an ideal world, I would also like the output the continue to be printed to the terminal, so I can remote in and monitor the output myself, but that's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./feeding_script.sh |
tee >(while read a; do [ "$a" == "12345" ] && </dev/null another_command; done)
```

Notes:

- `tee` splits the data stream; one copy goes to a "file" which is in this case a command `>(…)`, the other continues to the terminal;
- `</dev/null another_command` – this redirection prevents `another_command` from consuming data generated by `feeding_script.sh`.

Comment: Why is the `</dev/null` needed, it would share the same stdin as tee? It looks like the while & test would get the input first, but I'm not too sure what happens with process substitutions (or what happens if `another_command` takes a long time & the `feeding_script` data backs up)

Comment: @Xen2050 If `another_command` could feed itself from `stdin` (without redirection) then it would be able to consume any number of lines that follow the triggering `12345`. These lines would never go to `while read …`. I assumed they all should go there and be tested. But *if* the idea is to detect `12345` as a header that precedes data that *should go* to `another_command`, then `</dev/null` is wrong.